# Proving Divergence Free Behavior of Matrix Valued Radial Basis Function

Tags: vector-analysis, regression, interpolation, radial-basis-functions

I'm am using radial basis functions to interpolate magnetic fields, which are divergence free. I have found several research papers that state that the following takes a scalar valued Radial Basis Function (RBF) and turns it into a divergence-free matrix valued RBF:

\begin{equation}
   \Phi(x) = \{ \nabla \nabla^T - \nabla^2 I \} \Psi(x), \quad  \quad ( 1 )
\end{equation}

where $\Psi$ is scalar valued and I is an identity matrix

According to these papers, and assuming we are using a gaussian RBF: $ \Psi(r) = e^{-\epsilon r^2}$, where $\epsilon$ is the scaling factor. In two dimensions with $ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 $, equation (1) yields

$ \Phi_{11} = -( 4 \epsilon^2 y^2 - 2 \epsilon )e^{- \epsilon r^2} $

$ \Phi_{12} = 4 \epsilon^2 x y e^{- \epsilon r^2}$

$ \Phi_{21} = \Phi_{12}$

$ \Phi_{22} = -( 4 \epsilon^2 x^2 - 2 \epsilon )e^{- \epsilon r^2} $

**My first question is how do you arrive at this result?** If we just focus on $\Phi_{12}$, which should just be the product of two partial derivatives, I get:

$$ \Phi_{12} = \frac{\partial \Psi(r)}{\partial x} * \frac{\partial \Psi(r)}{\partial y} $$
$$ = ( -2 \epsilon x e^{- \epsilon r^2} ) * ( -2 \epsilon y e^{- \epsilon r^2} ) $$
$$ = 4 \epsilon^2 xy e^{-2 \epsilon r^2} $$

**My next question is once we arrive at the matrix valued RBF, how do you prove that it is divergence free?** Since the x/y components at each point in the resulting vector field are a sum of the  RBF "weights" multiplied by constants, shouldn't we be able to just take the matrix valued RBF and calculate its divergence? It should show that $ \nabla \cdot B = 0 $

Comment: I think $\nabla \nabla^T - \Delta$ is the double curl $\nabla\times\nabla\times$ and curls have zero divergence

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the first question, my confusion was that $ \nabla \nabla^T $ actually translates to the hessian. So the matrix valued RBF would be evaluated as:

$$
\Phi(x) = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial^2 \Psi(r)}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 \Psi(r)}{\partial x \partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2 \Psi(r)}{\partial y \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 \Psi(r)}{\partial y^2} \\
\end{matrix} 
\right] -
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\nabla^2 \Psi(r) & 0 \\
0 & \nabla^2 \Psi(r)\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

As for the second question, since the resulting vectors are a linear combination of a matrix valued RBFs and the weights, you only need to prove that one single matrix-valued RBF is divergence-free.

$$\left( \frac{\partial \Phi_{11}}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial \Phi_{21}}{\partial x} \right) + \left( \frac{\partial \Phi_{12}}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial \Phi_{22}}{\partial y} \right) = 0$$